# CPU soft lock up - NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

My Linux kernel version is, `4.1.52`. The processor architecture is `arm`.
Though the `Comm` field in the report shows `testd` which is my application, I dont think that could cause this issue. I believe the issue is in the kernel space itself. Refering to the back trace at the last part of the screen capture, I suspect `testd` was crashing and that triggered a CPU soft lock up. Following is the crash report.

```
NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [testd:6556]
[685228.664372] CPU: 1 PID: 6556 Comm: testd Tainted: P                4.1.52 #1
[685228.664373] Hardware name: XXXXXXX (XX)
[685228.664375] task: ffffffc00c4a4ac0 ti: ffffffc00988c000 task.ti: ffffffc00988c000
[685228.664387] PC is at _raw_spin_unlock+0x20/0x40
[685228.664394] LR is at ubifs_budget_space+0x4f4/0x5d0
[685228.664396] pc : [<ffffffc0005d5730>] lr : [<ffffffc00026d3d4>] pstate: 00000145
[685228.664397] sp : ffffffc00988f640
[685228.664400] x29: ffffffc00988f640 x28: ffffffc01dd87000 
[685228.664403] x27: ffffffc00988f718 x26: 00000000ffffffe4 
[685228.664405] x25: 0000000000001ff8 x24: ffffffc0009f1f90 
[685228.664408] x23: ffffffc000603000 x22: ffffffc01dd87920 
[685228.664410] x21: 0000000000000000 x20: 0000000000000000 
[685228.664413] x19: 00000000000000a0 x18: 0000000000000000 
[685228.664415] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: ffffffc0000f8ce8 
[685228.664418] x15: 0000000000000000 x14: 00000000f5ac9920 
[685228.664420] x13: 0000000000000002 x12: 0000000000000000 
[685228.664422] x11: 0000000000000001 x10: 0000000000000000 
[685228.664425] x9 : ffffffc00988f590 x8 : ffffffc00c4a5030 
[685228.664427] x7 : ffffffc01eb26000 x6 : 000000007ffff000 
[685228.664430] x5 : ffffffffffffffff x4 : 0000000000000001 
[685228.664432] x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : 0000000000000000 
[685228.664434] x1 : ffffffc00988c000 x0 : 0000000000000001 
[685228.664435] 
[685228.664437] Kernel panic - not syncing: softlockup: hung tasks
[685228.664440] CPU: 1 PID: 6556 Comm: testd Tainted: P             L  4.1.52 #1
[685228.664441] Hardware name: XXXXXXX (XX)
[685228.664443] Call trace:
[685228.664450] [<ffffffc0000871c0>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x150
[685228.664454] [<ffffffc000087324>] show_stack+0x14/0x20
[685228.664457] [<ffffffc0005d096c>] dump_stack+0x90/0xb0
[685228.664462] [<ffffffc0005ce0a4>] panic+0xd8/0x220
[685228.664468] [<ffffffc0001088d8>] watchdog+0x0/0x48
[685228.664473] [<ffffffc0000e04c0>] hrtimer_run_queues+0xa8/0x1e0
[685228.664476] [<ffffffc0000dfb84>] update_process_times+0x2c/0x70
[685228.664482] [<ffffffc0000ed330>] tick_nohz_handler+0x80/0x108
[685228.664488] [<ffffffc0003f2638>] arch_timer_handler_phys+0x30/0x40
[685228.664493] [<ffffffc0000d5998>] handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x78/0xa0
[685228.664496] [<ffffffc0000d14b4>] generic_handle_irq+0x34/0x50
[685228.664498] [<ffffffc0000d17c4>] __handle_domain_irq+0x5c/0xb8
[685228.664501] [<ffffffc000080c18>] gic_handle_irq+0x38/0x90
[685228.664504] Exception stack(0xffffffc00988f4f0 to 0xffffffc00988f620)
[685228.664507] f4e0:                                     000000a0 00000000 00000000 00000080
[685228.664511] f500: 0988f640 ffffffc0 005d5730 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000 0988c000 ffffffc0
[685228.664515] f520: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff
[685228.664519] f540: 7ffff000 00000000 1eb26000 ffffffc0 0c4a5030 ffffffc0 0988f590 ffffffc0
[685228.664522] f560: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002 00000000
[685228.664526] f580: f5ac9920 00000000 00000000 00000000 000f8ce8 ffffffc0 00000000 00000000
[685228.664529] f5a0: 00000000 00000000 000000a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[685228.664533] f5c0: 1dd87920 ffffffc0 00603000 ffffffc0 009f1f90 ffffffc0 00001ff8 00000000
[685228.664537] f5e0: ffffffe4 00000000 0988f718 ffffffc0 1dd87000 ffffffc0 0988f640 ffffffc0
[685228.664541] f600: 0026d3d4 ffffffc0 0988f640 ffffffc0 005d5730 ffffffc0 00000145 00000000
[685228.664544] [<ffffffc000083f00>] el1_irq+0x80/0xf8
[685228.664548] [<ffffffc00026d3d4>] ubifs_budget_space+0x4f4/0x5d0
[685228.664553] [<ffffffc0002573a8>] ubifs_write_iter+0x88/0x180
[685228.664558] [<ffffffc000159e70>] __vfs_write+0xa8/0x108
[685228.664560] [<ffffffc000159f14>] __kernel_write+0x44/0x110
[685228.664564] [<ffffffc000402154>] crashdump_write+0x44/0x88
[685228.664567] [<ffffffc000402b60>] crashdump_sync_buf+0x160/0x218
[685228.664570] [<ffffffc000402e4c>] crash_zdump_write+0x14/0x28
[685228.664576] [<ffffffc0001aa3d8>] dump_emit+0x130/0x160
[685228.664580] [<ffffffc0001a7074>] elf_core_dump+0xfa4/0x10e8
[685228.664583] [<ffffffc0001aaba8>] do_coredump+0x620/0x1108
[685228.664589] [<ffffffc0000a0560>] get_signal+0x2a8/0x530
[685228.664592] [<ffffffc00008697c>] do_signal+0x194/0x4f8
[685228.664595] [<ffffffc000086ed4>] do_notify_resume+0x64/0x70
```

Comment: Probably, you wanted to report that problem into the **bug tracker**. Stack Overflow is NOT the one of them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev My question here is could there be a CPU softlock up in the middle of the same process crashes. I am curious about a scenario like that. Not seeking for an exact answer. Seeking, if some one can give inputs to on how they would debug such issues.

Comment: "could there be a CPU softlock up in the middle of the same process crashes." - Almost any error could be a part of another error. "Seeking, if some one can give inputs to on how they would debug such issues." - Examine call trace closely, examine registers, examine memory, looking into the code,... - far **too broad** for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Set up crash dump. Examine what all processes were doing at the time. One of them is blocking in interrupt or lock. Start with your application.